# Какой применить паттерн проектирования для парсера документов?

Tags: парсер, шаблоны-проектирования

Пишу приложение - парсер экселевских таблиц. Внутри мои таблицы бывают размечены по разному, но у всех есть общие поля такие как "цена" или "кол-во" хотя эти названия и могут быть написаны чуть по разному.

Существуют ли какие-то стандартные паттерны проектирования для парсеров документов?

Comment: Любой. Можно даже антипаттерн, лишь бы парсил:)

Answer (score 0):

Часто используют Factory, но это для XML и прочих DOM, где есть вложенность. Для экселевской таблицы вряд ли требуется использовать именно паттерн. Просто создать класс для парсинга сущностей из таблицы